# @ElementCollection to non-collection field

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I have this @ElementCollection mapping so i could bring a legacy table with no unique id to work:

```
@Entity @Table(...)
@Inheritance(...) @DiscriminatorColumn(...)
class Notification { 
  @Id
  @Column(name="NOTIFICATION_ID")
  private BigInteger id;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(...)
class SomeNotification extends Notification {

  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name="LEGACY_TABLE", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="NOTIFICATION_ID"))
  private Set<NotificationInfo> someInformations;

}

@Embeddable
class NotificationInfo { // few columns }
```

I really can't touch the structure of LEGACY_TABLE, and now i am facing this:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(...)
class SpecialNotification extends Notification {

   // ? This is not a Collection, and it can't be a ManyToOne or OneToOne
   // since there is no ID declared on NotificationInfo.
   private NotificationInfo verySpecialInformation;

}
```

I know this is not supported by default, but i am fine to implement a Customizer to make it work with EclipseLink. The point is that for SpecialNotification instances, there will be only up to one NotificationInfo associated, instead of many, that is the case of SomeNotification.

Any thoughts about where i could start in the Customizer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this will work, but it's worth a shot. Try a combination of `@SecondaryTable` and `@AttributeOverride`

```
@Entity
@SecondaryTable(name="LEGACY_TABLE", 
        pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="NOTIFICATION_ID"))
@DiscriminatorValue(...)
class SpecialNotification extends Notification {
    ...
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name="someField", column=@Column(table = "LEGACY_TABLE", name="SOME_FIELD")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="someOtherField", column=@Column(table = "LEGACY_TABLE", name="SOME_OTHER_FIELD"))
    })
    private NotificationInfo verySpecialInformation;
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

Since `@SecondaryTable` by default makes an inner join, which may not be desired, it can be worked around with vendor specific APIs.

If you use Hibernate (which you don't, judging by the question tags, but nevertheless), it can be done with [@org.hibernate.annotations.Table](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-join), by setting `optional = true`.

With EclipseLink, you should make use of `@DescriptorCustomizer` and [DescriptorQueryManager#setMultipleTableJoinExpression](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.5/org/eclipse/persistence/descriptors/DescriptorQueryManager.html#setMultipleTableJoinExpression()(org.eclipse.persistence.expressions.Expression)), you can find a (not spot-on, but close enough) code example [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/SecondaryTable#Advanced_Multiple_Table_Configuration).

Comment: I thought abou that, but a SecondaryTable means a Inner Join. And this relationship is optional you know.

Comment: Yes, `inner join` would be used. One other option is to create a database view in which you would `outer join` optional data. It could even [support inserts and updates](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Views) , even if triggers are used to implement it.

Comment: If you were using Hibernate, you could mark it as optional
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-join

Comment: Also, read this http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Tables#Multiple_table_joins
With EclipseLink, it should be possible by implementing [DescriptorQueryManager#setMultipleTableJoinExpression()](http://javadox.com/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/2.5.0/org/eclipse/persistence/descriptors/DescriptorQueryManager.html#setMultipleTableJoinExpression(org.eclipse.persistence.expressions.Expression)), but I couldn't find any implementation examples.

Comment: Here is a useful piece of code https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/SecondaryTable

Comment: The VIEW idea would work, but i see a lot of other cases like that for other classes, so i really don't think creating tons of views along with triggers to make it possible to insert/update would be nice. I'd really prefered to find a way to settle this in a customizer.